# How to create a Queue of unsigned char array in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, queue

I am new in Queue (FIFO) and Qt. I want to create a Queue of unsigned char array in Qt. How to do it? Please help

```
unsigned char buffer[1024];
```

Comment: Do you want to build the queue on your own, or do you want to use the Qt API for queuing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the Qt API, then you can use the [QQueue](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qqueue.html) class -

```
 QQueue<unsigned char> queue;
 queue.enqueue(65);
 queue.enqueue(66);
 queue.enqueue(67);
 while (!queue.isEmpty())
     cout << queue.dequeue() << endl;
```

If you want to build the queue on your own, then I guess you can declare a `Queue` class like this -

```
class Queue
{
private:
    enum{SIZE=1024, EMPTY=0};
    unsigned char buffer[SIZE];
    int readHead, writeHead;

public:
    Queue()
    {
        readHead = writeHead = EMPTY;
    }

    void push(unsigned char data);
    unsigned char pop();
    unsigned char peek();
    bool isEmpty();
};

void Queue::push(unsigned char data)
{
    if((readHead - writeHead) >= SIZE)
    {
        // You should handle Queue overflow the way you want here.
        return;
    }

    buffer[writeHead++ % SIZE] = data;
}

unsigned char Queue::pop()
{
    unsigned char item = peek();
    readHead++;
    return item;
}

unsigned char Queue::peek()
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        // You should handle Queue underflow the way you want here.
        return;
    }

    return buffer[readHead % SIZE];
}

bool Queue::isEmpty()
{
    return (readHead == writeHead);
}
```

If you want to maintain a Queue of `unsigned char` array, then you will have to maintain a queue of `unsigned char` pointers -

```
QQueue<unsigned char *> queue;
unsigned char *array1 = new unsigned char[10];    // array of 10 items
array1[0] = 65;
array1[1] = 66;
queue.enqueue(array1);
unsigned char *array2 = new unsigned char[20];    // an array of 20 items
queue.enqueue(array2);

unsigned char *arr = queue.dequeue();
qDebug() << arr[0] << ", " << arr[1];
```

***Note***: You should take care of the memory cleanup after you are done with this queue. IMHO, you better avoid this type of design though.

Comment: But my requirement is each data in the Queue should be an array of unsigned char.

Comment: Your implementation is a Stack, Filo, Looking at pop. Queue should be fifo

Comment: @relascope: Well well, you are right! I never noticed it before.....fixed it, thanks!